Closed form expression for $\int_c^d \phi(x)\Phi(a+bx)dx$
I am wondering if there is a closed form expression for the integral:
$$
\int_c^d \phi(x)\Phi(a+bx)dx,
$$
where $\phi(x) := e^{-x^2/2}/\sqrt{2 \pi}$ and $\Phi(x) := \int_{-\infty}^x \phi(t)dt$ are the Gaussian probability density and cumulative distribution functions respectively. If no closed form expression, I am wondering about techniques to rigorously approximate such an integral (e.g. asymptotic).
Some cases where closed form expressions exist:

When $c=-\infty, d=\infty$: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\Phi(a+bx)dx = \Phi(a/\sqrt{1+b^2})$
When $c=0$ and $d=\infty$ and $a=0$, $\int_{0}^\infty \phi(x)\Phi(bx)dx =\frac{1}{2 \pi} (\pi/2 + \arctan(b))$
A similar expression to 2 when $c=-\infty$ and $d=0$.

Are there others? I'm particularly interested in settings where $c$ or $d$ are non-zero constants and $a \neq 0$.
